# Website snapshot for phishing detection?

Tags: phishing, honeypot

Is by just looking at the webpage snapshot, is a possible way to detect website phishing? Is is accurate enough?

Is we can detect the similarity of the URL, why do we need other sophisticated techniques such as image snapshot, in order to detect phishing from the browser?

If anyone knows anything about this, care to share. Any links/resources/research about it is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously because the URLs of the sites change all the time. Most of these phishers are hosted from an IP address without a domain. New ones pop up every day. How could anyone possibly predict if a site is phishing until they investigate it?

Comment: the users does not care enough to see their URL textbox at the browser. what about the website presentation? can the phishers mimicks a 100% similar site of the original ones?

Comment: Absolutely. Most of the time there's a slight variation, though. It's impossible to detect unless you know about the existing website already. I've seen a lot of RuneScape phishers in my time, and most of them are pretty good. Then there are the ones that imitate your desktop, and they do a pretty good job of that too. :)

Comment: thats shocking! if that is the concern, is there any space for doing website phishing detection using merely web snapshots? is it done before? furthermore, if phishers can imitate the real sites presentation, how image processing can be used to detect website phishing?

Comment: Sure, read the HTML and JavaScript and see if it matches the official company's URL, in a long index of names. Also, pattern recognition algorithms could be used.

Comment: What type of patterns that I must trace? is it the images or the codes of the site?

Comment: The code will be way different. By "pattern matching" I mean looking for similarities in a screenshot of the site to a screenshot of the official site. However, even the frequent occurrence of a brand name might be a red flag for phishing. The only surefire way to know if it's a phishing site is through user input.

Comment: Can you elaborate more about the user input? Is it regarding the way of the input box's behavior?

Comment: No, no, I'm just talking about input from the community, a voting system if you will. A lot of phishing filters use this.

Comment: Is server-based filter is better than client-based filter?

Comment: I say client-based might be better, because the user has the option to disable it, but it would still need to check whether each site is safe from some kind of database or server. If you plan on deploying on a large enterprise scale, I would probably recommend some kind of server, because there would be nothing to install on client machines. It all depends, but clients have to connect to some kind of central database.